# And automatically echo name from upload file

Tags: php

Good morning,
I would like to find the way to write the name of the uploading file in the Input value :

[image]

This my `add.php`:(value="Download/")

```
<?php

    $fichier_playlist = "tracklist.txt";
    if (isset($_POST['submitSave'])) {
        $playlist = simplexml_load_file($fichier_playlist);
        $map = $playlist->addChild("map");
        $map->addChild("file", $_POST["value"]);
        file_put_contents($fichier_playlist, $playlist->asXML());
    }
?>
<br>
<div class = "affichage">
    <center>
        <div class = "maps"><p>Map import</p></div>
        <form method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <tr><th>Entrer Map name:</th></tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="Download/<?php echo the upload name ?>"  name="value"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submitSave" value="save"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <form action="message.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br>
            <table>
                <tr><th>Add new Map name&nbsp;</th></tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="fileToUpload" name="the_file" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add & Save">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

How to find the upload name he appeared when selected the file next to the Input ID = "Filetoupload"

this my php upload code:
i can see this : echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded"
I would like to use it to fill my input text value in the add.php

```
<?php
    $uploadDirectory = "upload/";

    $errors = []; // Store errors here

    $fileExtensionsAllowed = ['gbx']; // These will be the only file extensions allowed 

    $fileName = $_FILES['the_file']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['the_file']['type'];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

    $uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensionsAllowed)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
      }

      if ($fileSize > 10000000) {
        $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (4MB)";
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded" . "\n";
        } else {
          echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
      } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
      }

    }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid - you are missing closing tags for table cells

Comment: It is really quite unclear what you are actually trying to ask here. Selecting the file is supposed to be step 1, "add and save" is supposed to be step 3 - and now filling that "download" field is supposed to be a step 2, in between - huh? I suppose you could be asking how to set that value on the client side, using JavaScript, _before_ the user submits the form - but then what would be the point, what are they supposed to "download", if nothing was uploaded yet?